# plot values and histogram of multiple data

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

For multiple (here: two) value lists I want to

- plot values as line or points into one diagram
- plot histograms into another diagram and
- assign the same color to the respective line plot and histogram plot

I've come up with a combination of two examples using ggplot2, which is still using different colors for line plot and histograms. Also it may be a bit redundant, creating

**How can I get the same color for line plot and histogram?**

Bonus: How can I shorten the piece of used source code?

*my result so far:*
[image: line plot and histogram of two value lists; still wrong coloring]

*Source Code (R):*

```
# input data lists
vals_x <- c(4, 3, 6, 7, 4, 6, 9, 3, 0, 8, 3, 7, 7, 5, 9, 0)
vals_y <- c(6, 6, 4, 8, 0, 3, 7, 3, 1, 8, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5)

# ------------------------------------------------
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# prepare data for plotting
df <- rbind( data.frame( fill = "blue", obs = vals_x),
             data.frame( fill = "red",  obs = vals_y))
test_data <- data.frame(
var0 = vals_x,
var1 = vals_y,
idx  = seq(length(vals_x)))

stacked <- with(test_data,
                data.frame(value = c(var0, var1),
                           variable = factor(rep(c("Values x","Values y"),
                                                 each = NROW(test_data))),
                           idx = rep(idx, 2),
                           fill_col = c( rep("blue", length(vals_x)), 
                                         rep("red",  length(vals_y)))))

# plot line
p_line <- ggplot(stacked, aes(idx, value, colour = variable)) + 
geom_line()

# plot histogram
p_hist <- ggplot( df, aes(x=obs, fill = fill)) +
                geom_histogram(binwidth=2, colour="black", position="dodge") +
                scale_fill_identity()

# arrange diagrams
grid.arrange( p_line, p_hist, ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is

1. Use the same data set in each `ggplot` object
2. Then use `scale_*_manual` (or some other `scale` call).

So

```
## Particularly awful colours
p_hist = ggplot(stacked, aes(x=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=2, colour="black", position="dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "yellow"))

p_line = ggplot(stacked, aes(idx, value, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "yellow"))
```

As an aside, I wouldn't use a histogram here; a boxplot or density plot would be much better.